# Exploding and Trimming Strings In PHP

Tags: php, string, explode, trim

i have format of string like this:

> 1PR009427S0000754

first let me explain this format. if you see the **"1P"** that means its the start of the part number of a product. Starting from the **"S"** that represents the serial number of the product. with this format of  strings i am able to split or explode that one string into two without any problem, not until i encounter these kind of string formats.

> 1P0005-00118-33S3S216
>
> 1PS-35C-602S6510873143
>
> 1P0005-00115-SPS3S216

if you guys noticed that for these new formats they got a couple of **"S"** in one string the problem is when I'm Exploding the string i used the **1P** to tell the program that it is the start of the part number and as soon as it sees the **"S"** that's the start of the serial number of the product. My concern is, when I'm exploding the new strings I'm getting a result of a wrong part number and serial number because of a couple of S that appears in the strings.

here is the sample of my program

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $text = explode("<br />",nl2br($_POST['pn']));
    foreach ($text as $key => $value)
    { //start foreach statements
        $precage = "0617V";
        $presym = "[)>";
        $partn = "1P";
        $serial = "S";

        $match = preg_match('/[)>0617V1PS]/', $value);
        if($match == true)
        {      

            $value2 = substr($value[1], 5);

            $result = explode("1P", $value2);
            $fin_pnresult = explode("S", $result[1]) ; 

            $serial1 = strrchr($value2, $serial);
            $fin_serial = substr($serial1, 1);
            $cageresult = substr($value2, 0, strpos($value2, "1P"));


        }
    }

?>
```

Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest you change the delimiters if you have any control over that part.

here's a quick and dirty approach to your current issue.

```
$string = "1P0005-00118-33S3S2161PS-35C-602S65108731431P0005-00115-SPS3S216";

$products = explode("1P", $string);

foreach ($products as $product) {
  if (strlen($product) == 0) continue;

  $first_s = strpos($product, "S", 1);
  if (substr($product, $first_s, 2) == 'SP') {
    $first_s = strpos($product, "S", $first_s+1);
  }
  $serial = substr($product, $first_s+1, strlen($product));
  $product_id = substr($product, 0, $first_s);
  echo $product_id."\n".$serial."\n\n";
}
// should give you
/*
0005-00118-33
3S216

S-35C-602
6510873143

0005-00115-SP
3S216

*/
```

Comment: the part number for the 0005-00115-SP and the serial number for this is 3S216 so that means the SP is included in the part number and the serial number starts after the SP :) how is that?

Comment: having a delimiter that can also a part of the values is not really a good way to do this. if you have any control at all how the values are passed to you then i suggest you change the delimiters.

Comment: i dont have a control for the data because it is being captured by a scanner to a matrix code do we still have any solution for that? but for the rest of part numbers the code work its just the part number that got -SP at the end. :) thank you though

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, it is extremely difficult to split correctly based on an `S` identifier for serial number. You may have data that may look like this: `1PABCRSQ` `S1234` where your part is supposed to be `1PABCRSQ` and serial is supposed to be `1234`. Splitting on `S` will not do the trick.

In another case your data may look like this: `1ABCRSSSSS1234` where your part is supposed to be `1ABCRSS` and serial is supposed to be `SS1234`. There is no easy way for a program to know which split of an `S` is really the part and which is the serial.

Assuming that the first S splits the part and the serial, the following code might be helpful to you:

```
<?php

    $data = '1ABCRSSSSS1234'; //'1P0005-00115-SPS3S216';

    // split by S
    $partInfo = explode('S',$data);

    // The first element of split array is the part. Remove 1P and show the part number
    echo "Data was $data\n";
    echo 'Part is ', str_replace('1P', '', $partInfo[0]), "\n";

    // Remove the first element and attach the remaining elements using an S
    array_shift($partInfo);
    $partInfo = implode('S', $partInfo);
    echo "Serial is $partInfo\n";

?>
```

Result:

```
Data was 1ABCRSSSSS1234
Part is 1ABCR
Serial is SSSS1234

Data was 1P0005-00115-SPS3S216
Part is 0005-00115-
Serial is PS3S216
```

If there are more rules to how part and serial needs to be split that explicitly define which S to consider, someone on SO can help with a better answer.

Comment: So what about if i got a first S on the part number?? just like this 1PS-35C-602S6510873143 wherein the part number is 1PS-35C-602 and the serial number is : S6510873143

Comment: If the first `S` belongs to the part number, the above strategy will not work. Therefore, rules will have to be clarified before splitting solely based on `S`. If you have an opportunity to change the formatting, I'd recommend separating the part and serial number by a `~` or `|`